# What exactly does \DeclareOldFontCommand and \DeclareRobustCommand do?

Tags: fonts, macros, latex-base

In the article class appears the following code related with the font selection:

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
```

What exactly does the commands at the code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The declaration

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
```

does

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\rm{\@fontswitch{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}}
```

Let's see what happens when LaTeX finds `$\rm a$` in the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\rm a$
\end{document}
```

Let's start:

```
\rm ->\protect \rm
```

`\rm` is a robust command, so this is its normal expansion. Now, since `\protect` is `\relax`, `\rm` is expanded:

```
\rm  ->\@fontswitch {\normalfont \rmfamily }{\mathrm }
```

Next `\@fontswitch` is expanded:

```
\@fontswitch #1#2->\ifmmode \let \math@bgroup \relax 
\def \math@egroup {\let \math@bgroup \@@math@bgroup
\let \math@egroup \@@math@egroup }#2\relax \else #1\fi 
#1<-\normalfont \rmfamily 
#2<-\mathrm
```

We see the arguments. Since we are in math mode, the "true" branch is followed, so the redefinitions of `\math@bgroup` and `\math@egroup` are performed and `\mathrm` is expanded:

```
\mathrm ->\protect \mathrm  

\mathrm  ->\relax \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathrm  \fi
\use@mathgroup \M@OT1 \symoperators 

\use@mathgroup #1#2->\relax \ifmmode \math@bgroup \expandafter
\ifx \csname M@\f@encoding \endcsname #1\else #1\fi \mathgroup #2\relax   
\expandafter \math@egroup \fi 
#1<-\M@OT1 
#2<-\symoperators
```

Again, we're in math mode (`\mathrm` has some code for disallowing its use outside of it); the tests are performed using the fact that the expansion of `\f@encoding` is

```
\f@encoding ->OT1
```

Now it remains to expand `\math@egroup`:

```
\math@egroup ->\let \math@bgroup \@@math@bgroup
\let \math@egroup \@@math@egroup
```

and the business is finished. Essentially, this is transformed into

```
${\mathrm{a}}$
```

If `{\rm a}` is found in text mode, then it becomes essentially

```
{\normalfont\rmfamily a}
```

that is, the old behavior of the `\rm` command is emulated.

This is why `{\sf\sl a}` won't use a slanted sans serif font, but a serif slanted one: it becomes equivalent to

```
{\normalfont\sffamily\normalfont\slshape a}
```

Moral: *never* use the old font commands. You gain nothing and lose much of the flexibility of the new ones. Well, after 18 years they aren't *really* new.

Answer (score 7):

Digging into [`source2e`](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) yields the following information:

> [`\DeclareOldFontCommand`] is the function used to create declarative font-changing commands that can
>   also be used to change alphabets in math-mode.

Basically the lines you quoted just make `\rm`, etc., equivalent to `\normalfont\rmfamily` in text mode and equivalent to `\mathrm` in math mode. This is done so that documents using these depreciated font commands still work correctly with LaTeX2e. (Note that the correct way to use declarative font-switches is `\rmfamily`, etc.)

> Fragile and robust commands are one of the thornier issues in LaTeX's
>   commands. Whilst typesetting documents, LaTeX makes use of many of
>   TeX's features, such as arithmetic, defining macros, and setting
>   variables. However, there are (at least) three different ocassions
>   when these commands are not safe. These are called ‘moving
>   arguments’ by LaTeX, and consist of:
>
> - writing information to a file,
>     such as indexes or tables of contents.
> - writing information to the
>     screen.
> - inside an `\edef`, `\message`, `\mark`, or other command which
>     evaluates its argument fully.
>
> The method LaTeX uses for making fragile commands
>   robust is to precede them with `\protect`.
>
> [...]
>
> [`\DeclareRobustCommand`] is a package-writers command, which has the same syntax as `\newcommand`,
>   but which declares a protected command.

Essentially, the use of `\DeclareRobustCommand` guarantees that nothing strange happens when (e.g.) a section title with a `\cal` is written to the `.aux` file.

`\DeclareOldFontCommand` uses `\DeclareRobustCommand` internally.