# \bf is an undefined command

Tags: errors, koma-script

I am very new to Latex and I am getting this error:

```
Class scrartcl Error: undefined old font command `\bf'.
See the scrartcl class documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... \maketitle
```

My template is never even using `\bf` but I still get this error. I am using the newest version of Texmaker.

Comment: clearly some code in your document is using `\bf` (it should use `\bfseries` but if you give no information it is hard to know what to change) or add  `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}` to your preamble to define `\bf`

Comment: Note this is unrelated to `texmaker` which is just the editor used for producing the tex source file.

Comment: I have no idea, I only know that when I am searching for \bf there are no results. So \bf is not here. I never wanted to use latex because of such errors. It is just frustrating.

Comment: @DominikK Most likely it's being used in a package which is (still) using the deprecated `\bf` command. Can you edit into the question your preamble (from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`).

Comment: The definition I suggest will make the error go, the use of `\bf` is in a definition of `\maketitle` in some file that you are using.

Comment: My template uses \maketitle, ok now things are a bit more clear. What can I do?

Comment: yes but the standard definition of `\maketitle` doesn't use `\bf` so you have a local redefinition somewhere.

Comment: Could this be in an .sty file?

Comment: uhh it is working. Thanks! Nothing better than having professors providing deprecated templates for latex beginners.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it got solved in the comment section.

Comment: If this rather small already frustrates you be warned: You will get worser errors.

Comment: @egreg I'm sure this is a duplicate of something but I don't think it's a duplicate of the one linked now. No answer in that question (mostly which shows implementing wiki markup) would tell a user of scrartcl how to avoid the error.

Comment: Class option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands`can be used. Example : [what to replace \it with in Math mode to make scrbook happy?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313638/43317)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message is showing that you have a local redefinition of (some command used in) the definition of `\maketitle` that uses `\bf`.

`\bf` has not been defined by default since 1993 so the code you are using seems a little old.

Rather than debugging that, simpler would be to use the definition of `\bf` as used for example by `article` class

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
```

will define `\bf` to work as it worked in LaTeX2.09.